# How can we write optimized ARM code for C++ program using loop unrolling and code pre-loading?

Tags: c++, arm

Below are the given c++ and ARM code for same program. Can you tell me this ARM code is optimized or not and how many does the loop requires(The size of the array n is large, and is a multiple of 64 elements and exclusive-OR bit-wise operation with the 8-bit mask and produces an output array outArr.)? What should I do to optimize the code using loop unrolling (process 4 elements at a time)?

c++ code:

```c++
// Gray scale image pixel inversion
void invert(unsigned char *outArr, unsigned char *inArr, 
 unsigned char k, int n)
{
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
 *outArr++ = *inArr++ ^ k; // ^ is bitwise xor
}
```

ARM CODE:

```
invert:
        cmp     r3, #0
        bxle    lr
        add     ip, r0, r3
.L3:
        ldrb    r3, [r1], #1    @ zero_extendqisi2
        eor     r3, r3, r2
        strb    r3, [r0], #1
        cmp     ip, r0
        bne     .L3
        bx      lr
```

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e16n43vqf) is useful.

Comment: not possible to determine from inspect how many cycles the code will take.  If you meant instructions then it is compiler and options specific, no reason to assume any two compilers will give the same result.  Nor the same compiler with different options or different versions.

Comment: First Thank you for your responses! I am trying to find that how many cycles does this subroutine take per array element when it is optimized and when it isn't.

Comment: `n is large, and is a multiple of 64 elements` Are pointers aligned to 64?

Comment: Without knowing the CPU, we don't know if it is super scalar with out of order execution capabilities nor how many pipelines are for each type of operation.  Even knowing that, trust your compiler until you have a LOT of reason not to.  It could be that SIMD is available to you as well which may speed this up more.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Here ARM9TDMI pipeline timings are assumed. About "n", array inArr of byte integers representing the pixels of a gray scale image of size n pixels.

Comment: Ok, if you can assume enough width and alignment, you should be doing those eor values a CPU word at a time, not per char.  If 64-bit, that is actually close to an 8 times speed up as memory access is almost always the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what 'code preload' means.  There is data preloading with the `pld` instruction.  It would make sense in the context of the sample code.

---

Here is the basic 'C' version given the assumptions,

> The size of the array n is large, and is a multiple of 64 elements and exclusive-OR bit-wise operation with the 8-bit mask and produces an output array outArr.

The code is probably not perfect, but meant to illustrate.

```
// Gray scale image pixel inversion
void invert(unsigned char *outArr, unsigned char *inArr, 
 unsigned char k, int n)
{
  unsigned int *out = (void*)outArr;
  unsigned int *in  = (void*)inArr;
  unsigned int mask = k<<24|k<<16|k<<8|k;

  /* Check arguments */
  if( n % 64 != 0) return;
  if((int)outArr & 3) return;
  if((int)inArr & 3) return;
  assert(sizeof(int)==4);

  for(int i=0; i<n/sizeof(int); i+=64/(sizeof(int)) {
   /* 16 transfers per loop 64/4 */
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k; // 1
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k; // 5
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k; // 9
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k; // 13
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
   *out++ = *in++ ^ k;
  }
}
```

You can view the [output on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c5dY8ovT1).

The `ldm` and `stm` instructions can be used to load consecutive memory addresses to registers.  We can not use all 16 ARM registers, so the core of the loop in assembler would look like this,

```
  ldmia  [r1], {r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11}  # r1 is inArr
  eor    r4,r4,r2   # r2 is expanded k
  eor    r5,r5,r2
  eor    r6,r6,r2
  eor    r7,r7,r2
  eor    r8,r8,r2
  eor    r9,r9,r2
  eor    r10,r10,r2
  eor    r11,r11,r2
  stmia  [r0], {r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11}  # r0 is outArr
```

This is repeated twice and the `R0` or `R1` can be checked against the array limits stored in `R3`.  You need to save all of the callee saved registers if you want to be EABI compliant.  The register set `r4`-`r11` can generally be used, but it will depend on the system.  You can also use `lr`, `fp`, etc if you save them and are not exception safe.

---

From the comments,

> I am trying to find that how many cycles does this subroutine take per
> array element when it is optimized and when it isn't.

Cycle counts are extremely difficult on modern CPUs.  However you have five instructions in the core with a simple loop,

```
.L3:
        ldrb    r3, [r1], #1    @ zero_extendqisi2
        eor     r3, r3, r2
        strb    r3, [r0], #1
        cmp     ip, r0
        bne     .L3
```

To do 32 bytes, this is 32 * 5 (160) instructions.  With 32 * 2 memory accesses.

The expanded options is just one 32byte memory read and write.  These will complete, with the lowest value available first.  Then just a single `EOR` instruction.  So it is just 10 instructions versus 160.  On modern processors the memory will be the limiting factor.  Because of memory stalls, it maybe better to only process four words at a time such as,

```
  ldmia  [r1], {r4,r5,r6,r7}  # r1 is inArr
  eor    r4,r4,r2   # r2 is expanded k
  eor    r5,r5,r2
  eor    r6,r6,r2
  eor    r7,r7,r2
  ldmia  [r1], {r8,r9,r10,r11}  # r1 is inArr
  stmia  [r0], {r4,r5,r6,r7}    # r0 is outArr
  ...
```

This (or some permutation) will allow the load/store unit and the 'eor' to not block each other, but this will depend on the particular CPU type. This topic is called instruction scheduling; it is more powerful than `pld` or data preloading. As well, you can use NEON or ARM64 instructions so that the body of the loop can do more `eor` operations before a load/store.

Answer (score 0):

These days, this is done like this:

```
void invert(unsigned char* const outArr, unsigned char const* const inArr, 
    unsigned char const k, std::size_t const n) noexcept
{
  std::transform(std::execution::unseq, inArr, inArr + n, outArr,
    [k](auto const i)noexcept{return i ^ k;});
}
```

You set `-Ofast`, cross your fingers and hope that good [code](https://godbolt.org/z/5jTPq19Tv) will be generated.

EDIT: You can also try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xKded9531):

```
void invert(unsigned char* const outArr, unsigned char const* const inArr, 
    unsigned char const k, std::size_t const n) noexcept
{
  std::transform(std::execution::unseq,
    reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t const*>(inArr),
    reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t const*>(inArr) + n/4,
    reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(outArr),
    [k=std::uint32_t(k<<24|k<<16|k<<8|k)](auto const i)noexcept{return i ^ k;});
}
```