# How many Instruction cycles will this instructions take?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, arm9

If i'm not wrong `ldrb r3, [r1], #1`  will take 3 instruction cycles, and similarly `add r4, r1, #2` will take 1 instruction cycles *not discussing the interlock delays here*, but i'm confused how many cycles will `cmp r4, r3` takes?

**Note that:** It's ARM ASSEMBLY with ARM9TDMI pipeline timings.

Comment: I personally think it will take 2 cycles, 1 for fetching data from r3, and one to decode and compare the r4 and r3 but its totally a blind opinion, idk much, please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: What references have you checked, and in what way are those references incomplete / unclear / ambiguous?

Comment: `cmp r4,r3` is a data processing instruction.  It is like `sub r4,r3`, but only affects the flags.  Data processing instructions (non PC/non shift) are 1 cycle (1S/1I).  You have to look at sequences of instructions for interlock and memory wait state considerations.  Ie, conclusions for `add r4,r1,#2` and `cmp r4,r3` should be the same if there is no memory interlock.  It is `bxx` that will take the extra cycles to act on the condition codes set by `cmp`.  The pipeline is pipelined, so (1S/1I) are happening with other instructions in the pipeline; usually you only count non-I.

Comment: Thank you @artlessnoise but I've already read the reference manual you mentioned, In chapter Number 7 where it defines the instruction cycles, I didn't read any guides about _CMP_ instruction, can you please tell the total cycle count according to your knowledge for the following code:
`invert:

ldrb r3, [r1], #1

eor r3, r3, r2

strb r3, [r0], #1

add r4, r4, #1

cmp r4, r3

bxge lr

b invert`

Comment: @artlessnoise - The code i mentioned in the above comment, According to me, Three cycles for _ldrb_ instruction, (2 cycles interlock because of load instruction) One cycle for _eor_ instruction, one cycle for _strb_ instruction, one cycle for _add_ instruction, two cycle for _cmp_ instruction, one cycles for _bxge_ instruction (average case while staying in the loop), three cycles for _b_ instruction.

Comment: of course you cant really count cycles since this is pipelined, but a compare takes no more than an add, the add has the extra step of writing back a result, but otherwise is the same number of steps and clocks.  So if your professor states that an add is one cycle then a cmp is one cycle as well...(note a compare is a subtract, but implemented as a add in logic, the inversions in and out of the adder are free)..

Answer (score 2):

You question is similar and uses [similar code as your classmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762197/how-can-we-write-optimized-arm-code-for-c-program-using-loop-unrolling-and-cod),

The loop core is,

```
        ldrb    r3, [r1], #1    ; 3 cycles
        eor     r3, r3, r2      ; 1 cycle
        strb    r3, [r0], #1    ; 1 cycle
        cmp     ip, r0          ; 1 cycle
        bne     .L3             ; 3 cycles
```

- `ldrb`, `eor r3,r3,r2` is an interlock similar to figure 7.2 and requires two interlock cycles.
- `str` and `cmp` are single cycles.
- `bne` is three cycles.

See section 2.2 for the pipeline stages.  It is taking approximately nine cycles.  Sections are from the [ARM9TDMI TRM](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5e8e356f88295d1e18d39b1c).

---

```
  ldmia  [r1], {r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11}  # 3 cycle
  eor    r4,r4,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r5,r5,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r6,r6,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r7,r7,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r8,r8,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r9,r9,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r10,r10,r2   # 1 cycle
  eor    r11,r11,r2   # 1 cycle
  stmia  [r0], {r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11}  # 1 cycle
```

This is 12 cycles for a transfer of 32 bytes, so it is approximately 24 times as fast.  Using R4 first is beneficial as per figure 7-4.

---

This alternate loop will take even longer at 13 cycles.

```
invert:  
  ldrb r5, [r1], #1  ; 3 cycles
  eor r5, r5, r2     ; 1 cycle
  strb r5, [r0], #1  ; 1 cycle
  add r4, r4, #1     ; 1 cycle
  cmp r4, r3         ; 1 cycle
  bxge lr            ; 3 cycles
  b invert           ; 3 cycles
```

This modification gives 9 cycles, the same as gcc,

```
invert:  
  ldrb r5, [r1], #1  ; 2 cycles
  add r4, r4, #1     ; 1 cycle
  eor r5, r5, r2     ; 1 cycle
  strb r5, [r0], #1  ; 1 cycle
  cmp r4, r3         ; 1 cycle
  blt invert         ; 3 cycles
  bx  lr             ; 0 cycles, not in loop
```

However, it is one more instruction.

Comment: No, but i've a different logical approach, I'm comparing r3 and r4 after incrementing r4 does that effect any instruction cycle ?

Comment: You can not use `r3` as the `ldrb` is overwriting it.  In the other question, the r3 is added to r1 and placed in `ip`.  As `r1` is auto-incremented, a test against the final pointer is sufficient.  You either need to use `r5` for the `ldrb r5, [r1]` or move `r3` somewhere else to use for the comparison.  Also, it is quicker to take the loop branch and then have a default as `bx`.  It is rare that `bxge` would be useful in a main loop.  It is better for argument checks.